# How can we append html within html string using javascript/typescript?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an HTML string like this:

```
    "Some text <span>something</span> some more text <span>something inside second span</span>...<span>nth span</span>"
```

I want to create a function that injects some HTML within each span, before each span tag close. Let's take the anchor tag so that the final HTML string becomes like this:

```
    "Some text <span>something<a>anchor</a></span> some more text <span>something inside second span<a>anchor</a></span>...<span>nth span<a>anchor</a></span>"
```

Please somebody tell me how I can achieve that? Please note that the injected dom will be the same throughout.

I have tried:

```
    content.replace("</span>","<a>anchor</a></span>");
```

But it only replaced first closing span tag from that html content string.

Comment: not 100% sure on what you're trying to accomplish, but could you just use variables from the .ts file?

Comment: The latest JS provides `content.replaceAll("</span>","<a>anchor</a></span>");`

Comment: You can also use regex for this `content.replace(/<\/?[/]+span[^>]*>/g, " <a>anchor</a></span> ")`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use replaceAll method to resolve this.